# Git push stopped working Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, centos

So after updating my CentOS my connection to github has stopped working. I removed all my id_rsa, config and id_rsa.pub. I then followed these instructions (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/). I copied my id_rsa to Github.

When I run

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

I am still getting the Permission denied (publickey).

My config file looks like

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

==== UPDATE ==========
Now when I run ssh -vT git@github.com

I get

```
/home/brian/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: AddKeysToAgent
/home/brian/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: UseKeychain
/home/brian/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

Comment: `copied my id_rsa to Github` Github wants the `.pub` file, not the private key.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. I copied the .pub file contents to github. The IdentityFile should point to the id_rsa NOT the id_rsa.pub